# Assigning value at useState() declaration vs useEffect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I have been using these two ways interchangeably however I am not sure which one is the more correct. their behavior seems to be the same but I am sure there is a use case for each. Anyone can help me understand what's the proper use for each case?

```
const [customer, setCustomers] = useState(props.location.state);
```

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setCustomers(props.location.state);
  }, []);
```

Comment: It's a common React anti-pattern to store passed props in local state. Just consume the props directly in the component. The reason it is considered anti-pattern is you've now two "sources of truth" and will possibly run into issues synchronizing them.

Answer (score 3):

You should normally stick to the first one. Calling the `setter` of `useState` may lead to undesired re-renders and decreased performance.

In the first block the customer is initialised directly and no re-render happens.  The `setCustomer` method will change the state and rerender the component. In the end the whole function will run twice which you can verify with a `console.log`.

```
const [customer, setCustomers] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  setCustomers(15);
}, []);

console.log(customer) // will first output 0 and then 15
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming in the second case, you have this as your `useState` statement:

```
const [customer, setCustomers] = useState();
```

The second one sets the value of customer on `componentDidMount`. So in the initial render, you will not have the appropriate value in your `customer` variable.
But yes, very soon after that the correct value will be set because of the code written in `useEffect`.

To clear it up, there will be 2 renders here (because the state variable value changes). In the first one, that won't be the case since the state variable has only one value from beginning.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is more effective.

```
const [customer, setCustomers] = useState(props.location.state);
```

If you use second one (by using `useEffect`), your component will be re-rendered again.

That's, your state variable `customer` will be updated in `useEffect` after DOM is initially rendered, this leads the 2nd re-render of the component.

But if you want `customer` to be updated by `props.location.state`, you need to add `useEffect` hook like the following.

```
useEffect(()=> {
    setCustomers(props.location.state);
}, [props.location.state]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the state's default value upon declaring it is probably the more correct way to go, since it does not trigger a re-render.

Every time you call a `setState` your component will be re-rendered, so when you do so in the `useEffect`, you will trigger an unnecessary re-render upon the component mounting, which could be avoided by doing the good ol'

> const [value, setValue] = useState(props.location.state)

While of course there are exceptions and many different use cases, setting an initial state in a `useEffect` is more useful, for example, when you have values you'd expect to change regardless of your component (for example from an external asynchronous API call):

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState(valueExpectedToChange)

useEffect(() => {
   setValue(valueExpectedToChange) // will trigger the rerender only when valueExpectedToChange changes
}, [valueExpectedToChange])
```